# Set edge of an object at a precise distance from another

Tags: modeling, mesh, snapping, measurement

I'm totally new with blender, and I want to measure the space that is present between the center of an object and a second object:

the first object is a road, and this is its center:
[image]

the second object is a rail, and I have to move it to exactly 9,012meters on the right of the y axis of the road:
[image]

how can i place it measuring the distance with precision?

Comment: right :) moreover measuring it seems to be quite difficult, because i cant select the right place in 3D environment :D i have 4 view (its blender 2.79b) but when it seems i selected the right point, in the other views i see i went too "deep" :D

Comment: hope so :) thanks anyway!

Comment: Wouldn't typing number when moving object do the work? Is there anything that is not possible to achieve?

Comment: well, typing numbers make the center of the rail stay at - let's say - 9m from the center of the squares plain; i am trying to put the left edge of the rail (the extreme left side of the rail) at 9m from the center of the road (orange dot)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One obvious solution seems to be snapping.

1. Select the road, and put 3D cursor there (*Object > Snap > Cursor to selected*)
2. Add > Object > Plane and set  it's size to **9,012 meters**. Now we have a measure.
3. Enable snapping to Vertex > Closest.
4. Move the rail along X axis and snap it to one corner of the 'measure' plane.
   It will be exactly 9m from the center of the road.

*New objects appear at 3D cursor. My plane size is 400 mm. Your's will be 9,012 m.*
[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks!! i was going mad :)

Comment: Glad to be of help :).